# Regex for string delimiter

Tags: regex

I'm looking for a regex to extract a substring based on two delimiters! The first delimiter will always be a `"`, but the second can be a `"` OR a `'`.

Example:

- Input string: `121232#"23343434"4RTRTTRT`
- Substring: `23343434`

OR

- Input string: `121232#"23343434'4RTRTTRT`
- Substring: `23343434`

For the first case the regex `.*\"(.*)\"` perfectly works! But how to add the OR condition for the character `'` possibility?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Didnt work for me on the regex101 tester...

Comment: The precise regex you are looking for seems to be this [\"']([^\"']*)[\"'] or even this [\"'](.*?)[\"'] Try playing here https://regex101.com/r/vTdkWy/1/